# Is it possible to return null if I get an empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter

I have two arrays of objects in Typescript, I am going through the first array to get the matches of the second array, my problem is that if it doesn't match it returns an empty array:

This is the first array:

```
let info = [
  {
    "brand": "bmw",
    "year": "2020",
    "country": "spain"
  },
  {
    "brand": "ford",
    "year": "2015",
    "country": "italy"
  },
  {
    "brand": "audi",
    "year": "2010",
    "country": "colombia"
  }
]
```

This is the second array:

```
let dataInit = [
  {
    "brand": "bmw",
    "year": "2020",
    "wheel": 18
  },
  {
    "brand": "audi",
    "year": "2010",
    "wheel": 17
  }
]
```

This is what I do to get the matches:

```
info.forEach((itemInfo: any) => {

  const { brand, year } = itemInfo

  const result = dataInit.filter((itemInit: any) =>
    brand.toUpperCase() === itemInit.brand.toUpperCase() && year.toUpperCase() === itemInit.year.toUpperCase()
  )

  const wheelRes = result[0].wheel;

  console.log(result)

})
```

This is what it returns:

```
1. [{"brand": "bmw","year": "2020","wheel": 18}]
2. []
3. [{"brand": "audi","year": "2010","wheel": 17}]
```

Finding no match returns [], is it possible to return nothing?

This is my problem:

I want to get the value of the 'wheel' property, but when an empty array comes I get an error: `Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'wheel')`

Comment: instead of filter you can use find. then result?.wheel will give undefined instead

Comment: The word "return" means something specific. Your code does not return anything; it logs messages to the console. All you really need is a simple `if ()` statement to log the result only when `result.length > 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Finding no match returns [], is it possible to return nothing?

Of course, just use `null` instead of the empty array.  However, that won't solve this problem:

> Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'wheel')

It would just replace that error with a new error, and for the same reason.

Instead, check the length of the array before trying to use it.  For example:

```
if (result.length > 0) {
    const wheelRes = result[0].wheel;
    // then whatever you plan to do with wheelRes...
}
```

---

Alternatively... from the use of `result[0]` (hard-coded first array element) it *seems like* you only ever expect one element to be found by the `filter` operation.  If that's the case then you can use `find` instead:

```
const result = dataInit.find((itemInit: any) =>
  brand.toUpperCase() === itemInit.brand.toUpperCase() && year.toUpperCase() === itemInit.year.toUpperCase()
)
```

If no match is found then `find` will return `undefined`, which you can check the same way:

```
if (result) {
    const wheelRes = result.wheel;
    // then whatever you plan to do with wheelRes...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if the array is empty before accessing it.

```js
info.forEach((itemInfo: any) => {

  const { brand, year } = itemInfo

  const result = dataInit.filter((itemInit: any) =>
    brand.toUpperCase() === itemInit.brand.toUpperCase() && year.toUpperCase() === itemInit.year.toUpperCase()
  )

  const wheelRes = result.length > 0 ? result[0].wheel : null; // Check if result array is not empty before accessing its first element

  console.log(result)

})
```